# Insert code templates via a keyboard shortcut

Tags: eclipse, keyboard-shortcuts, code-completion, code-templates

I have various code templates in Eclipse such as header comments and library functions that are frequently called (all stored in Preferences, C/C++ -> Editor -> Templates).  I figure there must be a way to map these to keyboard shortcuts, for example if I press <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>h</kbd> it will insert the contents of the template 'Header Comment Robotics Main' into the current editor.  I've been Googling and looking through preferences but can't find anything...there must at least be a plugin.

P.S. The IDE is actually Wind River Workbench v3.0.1, which is based of Eclipse v.3.3.1